# How to force text to break in next row?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a long word: my word goes out of the box.
Is there any solution so if I have for example this word lksadlkasdjlaksdjasdasjdklsajdlaskdaskldjasdkladja, to behave like this lksadlkasdjlaksdjasdasjdk- NEXT ROW->
jdlaskdaskldjasdkladja

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is your code..?

Comment: You might be looking for `word-wrap` css property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css `word-break` or `overflow-wrap` to accomplish this.  And also add css `hyphens` to indicate the breaks to your readers.

**overflow-wrap**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

**word-break**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

> Note: In contrast to word-break, overflow-wrap will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

**hyphens**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Both examples below:

```css
span {
  background: #eee;
  width:150px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

span:nth-child(1){
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}

span:nth-child(2){
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<span>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
<span>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the long strings.

```css
span{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span>jhfhgfhfghdfghdgfdfgdfgdfgdgfdghdgfdgfdgfdgfcgfvchgchvhvhgvchghg</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know * where*  you want the word to split, you can use a "soft hyphen": Insert this code at the desired position: `&shy;`

If the container is wide enough, the word will be displayed as one, if not, it will break at the soft hyphen:

```css
.a {
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.b {
width: 400px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<p class="a">lksadlkasdjlaksdjasdasjdk&shy;jdlaskdaskldjasdkladja</p>
<p class="b">lksadlkasdjlaksdjasdasjdk&shy;jdlaskdaskldjasdkladja</p>
```

Note: There is `word-wrap: break-word;` , but it will also break shorter words.